# HaProxy allow root path and some subpaths but deny all the rest

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy, haproxy-ingress

I would like to deny all the traffic on haProxy, unless path is:

1. /
2. /somepath
3. /someorherpath

Currently I have these rules:

```
acl allowed_pages path_beg /
acl allowed_pages path_beg /somepath
acl allowed_pages path_beg /someotherpath

http-request allow if allowed_pages
# if not allowed path/network, deny
http-request deny
```

But is not working as the / (root) rule allows for example /somethingthatisnotallower for example.

What am I missing here?

Edit: I have tried like this:

```
http request deny if !allowed_pages
```

But Im stil able to access /notwantedpath for example